# How to get Exm Messages(Message Id, subject, status) sent to each individual XDb contact programatically?

Tags: xdb, exm

I m sending mails to each individual contact programmatically using EXM with the help of EXM client API

Now I need to get the list of emails sent to each individual user without customization

In Sitecore XDb using xconnect (Sitecore 9.2), I can only get count of emails sent to each contact but unable to receive what emails were sent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not doable without customized `SendEmail` pipeline. By default the pipeline only fill the `personalized token` in the email that will be sent to `contacts`.

reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-exm-pipelines.html#idm45141554337600_body

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I figured out a way to get those details.

1. Whenever an email was triggered for specific Contact, sitecore creates an interaction for each email against individual contact.
2. This interaction consists of email specific events as well as Message Id, root id, Date time and so on.
3. Everytime a mail was triggered for that contact a new interaction gets added to the same contact under 'KeyBehaviorCache' facet.

So, with the help of contact - I looped through each interaction from KeyBehaviorFacet and with interaction data I found the message Id.